# Does android View reference passed to outside class create memory leak?

Tags: android, view, memory-leaks

i have a question. Does class like this:

```
public class AmountTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final TextView amountTo;

    public AmountTextWatcher(TextView amountTo) {
        this.amountTo = amountTo;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile(PatternHolder.amountPattern());

        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(s.toString());
        if (matcher.find()) {
            amountTo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            amountTo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            if (s.length() > 0) s.delete(s.length() - 1, s.length());
        }
    }
}
```

create a memory leak? do i need to hold a reference to such to it and clear it in onDestroy (or onDestroyView, whatever).

cheers
Wojtek

Comment: That depends on who all has a reference to the `AmountTextWatcher`.

Comment: like  `textView.setOnTextChangeListener(new AmountTextWatcher(textView));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AmountTextWatcher` is held by a `TextView`. The `AmountTextWatcher` holds onto the same `TextView`. Hence, these two objects, from a garbage collection standpoint, are part of the same object graph. The lifespan of those objects will be determined by who holds onto either of them.

If your only reference to the `AmountTextWatcher` is from the `TextView`, then the `AmountTextWatcher` will live as long as the `TextView` does. Normally, that will be as long as the activity that is showing the `TextView` lives.

IOW, your `AmountTextWatcher` will not be a memory leak, so long as the `TextView` it is associated with is not itself leaked.